# UIImage on Android

Tags: android, ios, uiimage, android-drawable

I'm migrating an **iOS** application to **Android**.

On iOS I have an `UIImage` object and I don't know which object can I use on Android. I thought I can use a `Drawable`.

*What do you recommend me?*

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/

Answer (score 0):

iOS equal to UIImageView in android is ImageView.

**PROGRAMATICALLY DOING IT**

```
 ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
    //setting image position and there are other properties to position ur imageview
 imgView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    //adding view to your layout(linear, relative....etc)
 yourLayout.addView(imgView);

 //Add this is how you set your Image
 this.imgView.setImageBitmap(localBitmap);
```

**IF YOU ARE USING XML FILES**

```
 //Get the reference of imageview
 imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

 //here you add your image
 imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourImage);
```